# How to replace functions in a base class?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to replace functions in a base class in a generic way and then restore the original base class function. The following program is an example. In function A.set1 I replace the A.f method explicitly with a new one and this works as test function B.t1() demonstrates.

What I actually want to do is replace A.f() in a generic way something like in function A.set2 which has the function to be replaced as a parameter but this does not work as function B.t2() demonstrates.

How can I make A.set2 to work the same way as A.set1, i.e. so that test methods B.t1() and B.t2() produce the same output.

The output right now is:

```
t1:
A.f
B.g
A.f
t2:
A.f
A.f
A.f
```

Code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import types

class A():
  def f(self):
    print("A.f")

class B(A):
  def g(self):
    print("B.g")

  def set1(self, new_f):
    original_Af = A.f
    A.f = new_f
    return original_Af

  def set2(self, new_f, old_f):
    original_Af = old_f
    old_f = new_f
    return original_Af

  def t1(self):
    print("t1:")
    self.f()
    original_f = self.set1(types.MethodType(B.g, self))
    self.f() # calls B.g()!
    self.set1(original_f)
    self.f()

  def t2(self):
    print("t2:")
    self.f()
    original_f = self.set2(types.MethodType(B.g, self), A.f)
    self.f() # Does not call B.g() but A.f(). Why?
    self.set2(original_f, A.f)
    self.f()

b = B()
b.t1()
b.t2()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python (and in general in high-level languages) arguments are passed by reference, but the reference itself is passed by value. In `set2`, the argument `old_f` is a reference to `A.f`, so you can modify any internal state of `A.f`, but you can't change the reference itself. `old_f = <something>` simply reassigns the value of the local variable.

```
  def set2(self, new_f, old_f):
    original_Af = old_f
    old_f = new_f
    return original_Af
```

Here you have a generic way of doing it using `getattr` and `setattr`.

```
  def set2(self, new_f, old, func_name):
    original_Af = getattr(old, func_name)
    setattr(old, func_name, new_f)
    return original_Af
```